# Creating XJC file , jaxb customization file

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, customization, xjc

How to generate .XJC file or jaxb customization file ?

Goggled but could not find any tool. Tried with XML Spy but could not
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you provide more information I can help you better :)

Comment: There is no XJC file. - Use an editor.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is an xjb example ..

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../your.xsd">

            <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='YourType']">
                <annox:annotate>
                    <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                        name="YourType" namespace="http://name.space.xsd">
                    </annox:annotate>
                </annox:annotate>
            </bindings>

            <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='User']//xsd:sequence//xsd:element[@name='certificate']">
                <xjc:javaType name="java.security.cert.X509Certificate" adapter="adapters.X509CertificateAdapter" />
            </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```